# Were the musicians in Disney's Princess and the Frog part of a funeral procession?

Tags: disney, the-princess-and-the-frog

At the beginning of Disney's 2009 animated feature film The Princess and the Frog there are several scenes that feature a troupe of musicians walking across the shot playing their instruments while wearing brightly colored clothing.

In one scene this troupe includes the lead villain.

In some cultures found in the region it is traditional to hold a similar procession as part of a funeral, as celebration of a person's life. Was this the case in this animated feature film, or was it just a random background scene?

Has this question ever been asked/answered in verifiable media, for example as part of a director's commentary, panel event or media spotlight?

Comment: Nothing of any use in the official graphic novelisation, nor in the *Essential Guide*.

Comment: Nothing in the maker's Audio Commentary (Ron Clements and John Musker, producer Peter Del Vecho) of any use. They're still chatting about the setup for the film at this point...

Comment: For the record, that's not Dr. Facilier leading the marching band. It's another top-hatted invidividal

Comment: @Valorum It looks like this varies between localizations, they do this some times, like how the Candy Crush racer characters have different looks in different regions, or the planes from Planes  use colors from national airlines in some scenes. I don't get this change though.

Comment: I don't see any evidence that they've localised this film to different markets. Note that this is a hand-drawn film, not digital, so adding in new characters is a substantially bigger deal

Comment: @Valorum, It wasn't hand draw, most of it was made using the Harmony engine for the characters and Maya for the Buildings and other structures that characters needed to move around in 3 dimensions.. There's actually quite a bit of localization in this movie, for example the language in fairy tale books varied between regions.

Comment: @Aargh - They talk quite extensively in the audio commentary about how the characters are drawn onto cel paper. There's lots of CGI, but this section isn't one of those. A good question to ask though would be something like ***"What localisation is there in Princess and the Frog?"***

Comment: @Valorum, The hand drawn section was the art deco scene during the musical number in the old sugar mill. They also did hand drawn story boards. The scene in question was done using Harmony for the foreground and Maya for the background.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a troupe of musicians practicing for Mardi Gras. There's no indication that it's a funeral procession.

From the *[official novelisation](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Princess-Junior-Novelization-Trimble-2009-10-13/dp/B01FGLH31G)*.

> Tiana looked out the window. **It was close to Mardi Gras, a time when
> New Orleans came alive with even more food, music, people, and parties
> than usual. ...**
>
> ... One man offered her a flower, but Tiana barely noticed. The street was
> so crowded with musicians, dancers and other performers that they
> nearly blocked Tiana's way as she stepped off the street car. It was
> true what they said about New Orleans during Mardi Gras: day or night,
> **it always seemed as if there was a party going on somewhere**. But Tiana
> remained so focused on getting to Duke's Diner that **she almost bumped
> right into a marching band**.
>
> <sub><sup>[*Disney's The Princess and the Frog: Junior Novelization by Irene Trimble.*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Princess-Junior-Novelization-Trimble-2009-10-13/dp/B01FGLH31G)</sup></sub>

To back this up, we do see the full procession in the street. There's no hearse (horse-drawn or otherwise) behind them.

> [image]

Nor are there any indications that it's anything other than an enthusiastic marching band in the concept artwork from [*The Art of Princess and the Frog*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Art-Princess-Frog-Jeff-Kurtti/dp/0811866351).

> [image]

Comment: It's a bit too small to be a true '[second line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_line_(parades))' parade, but they could be trying to attract "followers" to take to a local bar or restaurant. Basically a form of [barking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barker_(occupation))